# How to best remove redundant calls from a code block, that should be executed when the block exists successfully?

Tags: python, python-3.x, refactoring

I'm trying to simplify the following code (removing the redundant prints), but can't find a satisfying way to do this:

## original code

```
def main():
    if expression1:
        print("1")
        print("always_do_this")
        return
    if expression2:
        print("2")
        print("always_do_this")
        return
    # ... possibly more expressions and thus redundancy

    print("always_do_this")

    # do something else
```

My first idea was a `try-(except-)else` combination, but the `else` is not executed on a return in the `try`-block.

## Solution 1 - extracting into a separate function

```
def func():
    if expression1:
        print("1")
        return True
    if expression2:
        print("2")
        return True
    return False

def main():        
    result = func()

    print("always_do_this")

    if result:
        return

    # do something else
```

## Solution 2 - workaround using finally

```
def main():

    error = False
    try:
        if expression1:
            print("1")
            return
        if expression2:
            print("2")
            return
    except:
        error = True
        raise
    finally:
        if not error:
            print("always_do_this")

    # do something else
```

Surely there must be a better way to achieve this in python?

PS: Also any ideas for a better title would be appreciated...
PPS: I'm not directly asking about (subjective) codestyle, but wondering if there is a way to write this that I didn't consider (e.g. a language construct/pattern, that also makes the code more concise/cleaner; obviously there are a lot worse ways).

Comment: Sorry, I am not understanding exactly which lines you want executed and which you do not. Could you put some comments or more detailed `print` statements so that we know how you want to control your flow?

Comment: I just realized that myself and added additional prints. Did you already see this edit?

Comment: Still confusing, but I am closer... lol. Do you mean to say `if someexpr:` and then `if not someexpr:`? Why do you test for boolean of someexpr twice? and you want the `main()` to `return` inside those if statements in your original code so that it doesn't execute anything outside of it if it enters that if block?

Comment: Oh, I see your problem. I tried to explain this in the first comment, but will edit it. And yes `main` should return, but not before `print("always_do_this")`.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your flow did not enter the first two `if` blocks by checking for the opposite of the first two `if` statements joined by an `and`so that you can execute "do something else" only if the first two if statements failed. Return at the end instead of in the middle of the if statements.

```
def main():
    expression1 = True
    expression2 = False

    if expression1:
        print("1")
    elif expression2:
        print("2")

    print("always_do_this")

    if not expression1 and not expression2:
        # do something else

    return
```

Comment: This does not do an early exit if `expression1` is `True` and doesn't scale with a higher number of expressions.

Comment: Fixed it to `elif` to avoid running `print('2')`. As for scaling, there will always be an `if` statement to test for boolean and an expression with it. You could also use a `flag = False` and set it to `True` inside any of the initial `if elif` block, then test for the `flag` in the end for the `#do something else` block.

Comment: Yeah, a flag is probably the best idea here, but not much different than a simple function call (could easily remove the parameters in the original code with `functools.partial`). I was just hoping that I missed something else...

Answer (score 0):

If the thing you always want to do is closing a file, I would use a `with` statement. In a more general case you can create your own context manager to have full control of what gets run at the end.

Sample code:

```
class my_closer:
   def __enter__(self):
      return True
   def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
      if type is None:
          print("always_do_this")
      else
          print("An exception was raised: {}".format(type))

def main():
   with my_closer() as c:
      if someexpr:
         print("1")
         return
      if someexpr:
         print("2")
         return
```

I added a superfluous `else` to print something about the exception in case of error, but leave it out to reproduce your original code more accurately.

This code is not shorter than yours with the trivial `print` statement, but I like this method for more complex "closer" code.

You can also define the context manager this way using the `contextlib` library:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def my_closer(*args, **kwds):
   try:
      yield True
   except:
      #print("some error happened")
      raise
   else:
      print("always_do_this")
```

References:

- http://effbot.org/zone/python-with-statement.htm
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#typecontextmanager
- https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager

Comment: This does not behave the same way as the original code as it is now equivalent to my try-finally solution if it didn't have the `error` variable.

Comment: Question: if there is an error, do you want the always-do-this code to get run or not? I tested and if I raise an exception within the `with` statement the line does get printed. This is what you would want for closing a resource, but maybe it's not with your code?

Comment: Correct, it should only be executed for successful exists, as the title says. (Even though it is some kind of ressource, it has to be handled differently in case of an error)

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of your question. In this case, I think your try/except/finally is the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks. That just looks way too complex for such a simple situation.

Comment: I take it back, the `type` argument is `None` on normal exit, but has the exception when there is an error. I'll edit my answer to have the behaviour you want.

Comment: Maybe a more concise way would be a generator https://docs.python.org/3/library/contextlib.html#contextlib.contextmanager. Although that looks very similar to my try-finally solution...